# Angular firestore query to firestore document

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have below query

```
    selectedUser$: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
    this.selectedUser$ = this.userCollection.ref.where('uid', '==', key)
```

Throwing error

> Type 'Query' is not assignable to type
>   'AngularFirestoreDocument'.   Property 'ref' is missing in type
>   'Query'.

I tried

```
this.selectedUser$ = this.userCollection.ref.where('uid', '==', key).get()
```

no success

Basically, I want the query to return firestore document

Comment: Tried `this.selectedUser$ = this.userCollection('yourCollection', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', key) )` ? This will retrieve the document on valueChanges().subscribe()

Comment: yourCollection??? userCollection is given there

Answer (score 16):

The error your getting is because you're mixing the firebase native api & angularfire.

```
selectedUser$: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
```

Calling `.ref` on your `AngularFirestoreCollection` converts it to type `firebase.firestore.CollectionReference`

That being said, there are 2 possibilities to solve your issue:

Using `angularfire`:

I'm assuming your userCollection looks something like this: `this.afs.collection<User>`. Since you're querying a collection, there is no way to ensure your query predicate `uid == key` is unique in firebase. So you query the collection and `limit()` the result. This will return you an array with one document. `flatMap()`will return you a single user.

```
this.afs.collection<User>('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', key).limit(1))
   .valueChanges()
   .pipe(
       flatMap(users=> users)
   );
```

Using the `firebase` native api:

```
const query = this.usersCollection.ref.where('uid', '==', key);
query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log('no data found');
    } else if (querySnapshot.size > 1) {
        console.log('no unique data');
    } else {
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            this.selectedUser$ = this.afs.doc(documentSnapshot.ref);
            // this.afs.doc(documentSnapshot.ref).valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
            });
        }
    });
```

This way it's a bit easier to chain multiple `.where` clauses if it's needed

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with the latest versions: 2021-July

```
this.store
    .collection("Products",ref=>ref.where("stock","==",10))
    .get()
    .subscribe(data=>data.forEach(el=>console.log(el.data())));
```

PS: I'm using get() and no event listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afs.collection<User>('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', key).limit(1))
      );
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -4):

It will be easier to help you if you add more details about the structure of your Firestore collection and your typescript file.

However, to query the collection I do the following:

1. Define a private AngularFirestore in the constructor.

   ```
   constructor(
     private afStore: AngularFirestore,
   ) 
   {
   }
   ```
2. Define the query and pass the result to the AngularFirestoreDocument.

   ```
   this.selectedUser$ = this.afStore
       .collection('TheNameOfYourCollection').doc<any>(key);
   ```

Comment: Here we need to pass the id generated by firestore only, I need to query on a field