# Firebase query with where condition

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a 'client' collection and I intend to get the doc that satisfies the 'where' condition below:

```
this.angulfirestore.collection('client', ref=>ref.where('name', '==', 'Karl')).get()
.subscribe(datas => datas.forEach(el=>{
  if(el.exists === true){
    console.log('OK');
} else {
  console.log('No');
}
})
)
```

The collection has a doc that has the same field name as Karl.
It happens that if the condition is not satisfied, that is if I change the value of the field name to another one that doesn't exist in the doc the else does not show anything in the console.
Someone help me please...and thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `datas` is a `QuerySnapshot` that contains any-and-all documents that match your condition. Its `forEach` loops over the results, and for each of those you check whether the `el` document snapshot `exists`.

---

If there are results, each of the snapshots will of course exist. There is no way for `exists` to be false in that scenario.

If there are **no** results, `forEach` has nothing to loop over. It will never enter the loop in that case.

So either way, there is no case where `el.exists` will ever run and be `false`.

---

What you want to do is check whether the `QuerySnapshot` has any results. Something like this:

```
.subscribe(querySnapshot => {
  if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log('No');
  } else {
    querySnapshot.forEach(docSnapshot => {
      console.log('OK');
    })
  }
})
```

Also see: [Angular firestore query to firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071245/angular-firestore-query-to-firestore-document)